# Which Stripe webhooks confirm Subscription and Product payments?

Tags: stripe-payments

The Stripe API is quite overwhelming. I found out, that there are some webhooks which are present because of backward compability (i.e.: Plan, Charge..)

**My intention is quite "simple":**

My app should allow users do something, when they successfully paid their subscriptions or products. Some of the things I sell are Subscriptions and some are "One Time"-payments.

I don't know which webhooks I should use to and not miss any payments.

There is:

- invoice.paid
- invoice.finalized
- payment_intent.succeeded
- order.payment_succeeded
- checkout.session.completed
- checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded

and of course some callbacks if payments are failed:

- invoice.payment_failed
- invoice.finalization_failed
- payment_intent.payment_failed
- checkout.session.async_payment_failed
- order.payment_failed
- ...
- ..

My current assumption is that

- invoice.paid
- invoice.payment_failed

could be "the right" hooks

My second assumption is

- payment_intent.payment_failed
- payment_intent.succeeded

Am I going into right direction?

EDIT:

I add the content of Webhooks:

| Webhook | status | contains recurring products | product | contains one-time products | plan | customer | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| customer.subscription.created | incomplete | yes | id |  | yes | customer | — |
| customer.subscription.updated | active | yes | id |  | yes | customer | — |
| payment_intent.created | requires_payment_method | — | id | — | — | customer | — |
| payment_intent.succeeded | succeeded | — | id | — | — | customer | billing_details.address |
| invoice.finalized | open | yes (lines) | yes | yes | yes | customer | customer_address |
| invoice.updated (contains "previous_attributes") | paid | yes (lines) | yes | yes | yes | customer | customer_address |
| invoice.paid | paid | yes (lines) | yes | yes | yes | customer | customer_address |
| invoice.payment_succeeded | paid | yes (lines) | yes | yes | yes | customer | customer_address |
| checkout.session.completed | complete | — | — | — | — | customer | billing_details.address |

Comment: I agree. What a mess! What I ended up doing was putting a breakpoint in my webhook and then doing all the things I could think of to do. Subscribe, unsubscribe, fail payment, etc. Then I took note of which events fired. And then went down into each object to see what might be useful/redundant. A mess. But better than reading the docs which have partial hello-world examples.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the recurring payments, the short answer is your current assumptions are correct as per this [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks) you should be listening for `invoice.paid` and `invoice.payment_failed` for handling recurrent payments. You might also need to listen to `customer.subscription.updated` for accounting for subscription changes and `invoice.payment_action_required` for instances where something like 3DS (SCA) is needed and you might need to get your customer back to make a confirmation of the payment on-session.

When it comes to one-off payments, if you’re using [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?integration=checkout) than you should listen to `checkout.session.completed`, on the other hand if you’re using the [Payment Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/intents) API, then you should listen to `payment_intent.succeeded`, `payment_intent.payment_failed` and `payment_intent.requires_action`.

Keep in mind if you’re listening to both `payment_intent.*`  and `invoice.*` events, the Payment Intent events will also fire for recurring payments. If the `invoice` [field](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-invoice) is not null in the Payment Intent received in that event then ignore this event since it will be handled in the `invoice.*` events instead.

You can find all event types and descriptions [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types).

Comment: Thank you so much, many events seem bit dedundant, this is what confused me.